# Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection. Loading network status failed (connection timeout - 178.254.13.126:443)

Tags: connection

I was able to connect to the Tor network one time months ago on my desktop. since then I've had to use my android phone - no problems.

This is the log message I get after the failed connection:

```
4/9/2017 20:44:51 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/9/2017 20:44:51 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/9/2017 20:44:51 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/9/2017 20:44:51 PM.200 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/9/2017 20:44:51 PM.200 [NOTICE] Renaming old configuration file to "C:\Users\Pope\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc.orig.1" 
4/9/2017 20:44:51 PM.800 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
4/9/2017 20:45:14 PM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
4/9/2017 20:45:14 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
4/9/2017 20:45:15 PM.000 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
4/9/2017 20:45:15 PM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
4/9/2017 20:53:46 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host 22F08CF09764C4E8982640D77F71ED72FF26A9AC at 144.76.163.93:9001) 
4/9/2017 20:53:46 PM.600 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
4/9/2017 20:53:46 PM.600 [WARN]  9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
4/9/2017 20:54:00 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/9/2017 20:54:00 PM.900 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/9/2017 20:54:00 PM.900 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/9/2017 20:54:00 PM.900 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
4/9/2017 20:59:32 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/9/2017 20:59:32 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/9/2017 20:59:32 PM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/9/2017 20:59:32 PM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/9/2017 20:59:54 PM.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 11; recommendation warn; host F9246DEF2B653807236DA134F2AEAB103D58ABFE at 178.254.13.126:443) 
4/9/2017 20:59:54 PM.100 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
4/9/2017 20:59:54 PM.100 [WARN]  11 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
4/9/2017 21:02:45 PM.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 12; recommendation warn; host 7BE683E65D48141321C5ED92F075C55364AC7123 at 193.23.244.244:443) 
4/9/2017 21:02:45 PM.600 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
4/9/2017 21:02:45 PM.600 [WARN]  12 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
4/9/2017 21:02:45 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/9/2017 21:02:45 PM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
4/9/2017 21:02:45 PM.600 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
4/9/2017 21:02:45 PM.600 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: This is just timing out, I assume the rest of the network works okay? If so then try using some bridges like the default obfs4 or meek

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with your terminology. Can you please offer more detail? I'm new to this. obfs4 or meek? Can I download those? Sorry I just figured it out!

Comment: THANKS! It worked when I switched to Meek! Thank you so much!